# Objective-c app for iPhone and mysql

Tags: mysql, ios, frameworks

I'm planning to build an iPhone application in Objective-C that will require to be connected to an MySQL database.

Should I,

1. Use a framework and query the database directly from the application
2. Go through a PHP page that will get the data, transform it into JSON and send it to the application?

Is the first solution secured ? Which framework do you recommend?
How can I secure the server and the access to the database as it will be open to anyone on the internet?

Thank you for your precious answers.

Comment: try coredata which may be helpful to you..

Answer (score 5):

Most probably point 2 is used in mobile appliction.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if the MySQL DB is based on the internet, I would expose a Webservice to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on your database size. If it is very large then you should use `Webservice` to received data from server. You can use secure `HTTP` base server connection. Very large size database is not recommended to stored in local(phone memory).

If your database is small in size and not frequent updating then you can use `Sqlite` as your database. This is most preferable.